# Download and open file using Chrome Capybara Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing tests that downloads a PDF and opens it in browser so that I can confirm some content within.  I'm struggling to find a solution to configure Chromedriver to download and open instead of saving to the downloads folder (default).

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently (2015-07-12) this is an open issue in chromedriver.
See: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1081 for details.

You may be able to work-around it by configuring the chrome profile.  Based on the information in the bug you might try something like:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_pdf do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    "chromeOptions" => {
      "excludeSwitches" => [ "test-type", "ignore-certificate-errors" ],
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

And set:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome_pdf
```

or just switch to this driver when needed:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :chrome_pdf
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back to you.  Thank you