# Sending capabilities / switches to chromedriver with Capybara

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I can't figure out the syntax for sending switches to ChromeDriver when using Rspec/Capybara:

For example:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  #caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"excludeSwitches" => [ "--ignore-certificate-errors" ]})
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--window-size=200,200" ]})
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

I have tried the above with/without the proceeding -- before the switches.

Looking at the doc it wants to use `Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome` but I don't see how that fits in when using Capybara.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182716/download-and-open-file-using-chrome-capybara-selenium)?

Answer (score 8):

To setup Capybara with the Chrome driver with customized capabilities:

**Selenium 3**

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :chrome,
    :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      'chromeOptions' => {
        'args' => [ "--window-size=200,200" ]
      }
    )
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
```

**Selenium 4**

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument("--window-size=200,200")

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                             capabilities: options,
                                       browser: :chrome)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
```

Comment: @Ewan Put `--no-sandbox` in the `args` array

Answer (score 0):

One can set chrome profile with below code snippet, I am using it, without any issue.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.read_timeout = 200
    capabilities = {
        :idleTimeout => 300,
        :version => 57,
        :browserName => 'chrome',
        :platform => 'Windows 7',
        :commandTimeout => 500,
        'chromeOptions': {
                            'prefs': {
                                'credentials_enable_service': false,
                                 'profile': {
                                     'password_manager_enabled': false
                                 }
                            }
                        }
    }
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                                   :browser => :remote,
                                   :url     => url,
                                   :desired_capabilities => capabilities
    )
```